# Intercept a request containing a .cvs file and send it unaltered to server

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am making an extension that needs to listen to requests (or the download folder) and detect when a user downloads a .csv file from a specific lists of sites. The .csv file (or possibly changed to another format like clear text) must then be send **unaltered** to an external server to verify its contents.

I am not 100% how this can be achieved in Chrome while making sure the user haven't tampered with the file. I am thinking of possible solutions to this using the Chrome extension API.

I take it you need to listen to incoming requests using the webRequest and check when the content-type is set to .csv, after that the request content should be send to a server. Can you handle it like so:

- Grab the unaltered content of request using various methods in the webRequest API?

or

- Grab the request url from the detected .csv request and have the Chrome extension request it once more using a XHR and then send it to the server?

or

- Grab the request using the webRequest API and proxy it directly unaltered to a server?

or

- Detect the request using the webRequest API and grab all the local cookies need to make the authorize the user and send it to the server and have it mimic the user to download the file?

or

- Listen to the download folder and whenever a new file have been download from the specific site then send it unaltered to a server?

or

- Grab the request using the webRequest API and make calculate hash sum of the content so that I can detect any changes to it?

Do anybody know how this can be done. The essential thing is that I can get the request content (in this case a .csv) file unaltered?

An example:

```
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function(item) {
    if (item === '.csv') {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Download the .csv file
        xhr.open("GET", https://download.csv, true);
        xhr.send();

        // Send it to the server
        xhr.open("POST", https://server.url, true);
        xhr.send('csv file');             
    }
});
```

Comment: webRequest API does not expose the body (the file contents) of the server response. Use [chrome.downloads.onCreated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) event to catch the URL and send it to the server.

Comment: So I listen for the correct file download and then send the downloaded request body to the server? Something like this (updated the above post with an example).

Comment: No, you don't need the request body. It's the response body you need but there's no way to get the response body without redownloading the URL via XHR/fetch in your code. Well, there's chrome.debugger API, but its other restrictions would make it unusable for a generic eavesdropping you want.

Comment: So the work flow goes as this:

1. listen to downloads
2. xhr to redownload the .csv file
3. xhr to send the contents to the server

I have updated an example above. Thanks.